# PIG flatten vs group on nested bag

Tags: apache-pig

I'm learning PIG and I have a question that I know might be in books, but unfortunately I don't have the time to do the research.
I have two pipelines:

(option 1):

```
a = LOAD 'geolocation' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = LOAD 'truck_mileage' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
c = join a by truckid, b by truckid; 
d = foreach c generate SUBSTRING(rdate,3,5) as year, event, mpg;
e = foreach d generate flatten(year) as year, event, mpg;
f = group e by year;
g = foreach f generate group, AVG(e.mpg);
x = limit g 10;
dump x;
```

I load 2 files, then join then, then I take the last 2 digits of the date to get year, after I used flatten to simplify things before grouping to get average of mpg.

(option 2):

```
a = LOAD 'geolocation' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = LOAD 'truck_mileage' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
c = join a by truckid, b by truckid; 
d = foreach c generate SUBSTRING(rdate,3,5) as year, event, mpg;
f = group d by year;
g = foreach f generate group, AVG(d.mpg);
x = limit g 10;
dump x;
```

Same thing, but I don't use flatten to group and then get average of mpg.

I get the same results but, is there a significant difference? In this case the dataset I used is not big, but I'm curious about how it would be the case if I have a couple of millions of records.

Thanks.

Comment: significant difference in which parameter?

Comment: performance if the dataset gets big.